# What is the equivalent of weight_filler "gaussian" from Caffe in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

I'm trying to convert a Caffe model to tensorflow. In Caffe my convolutions are initialized like this:

```
weight_filler {
  type: "gaussian"
  std: 0.01
}
bias_filler {
  type: "constant"
  value: 0
}
```

How can I get the same initialization in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`tf.truncated_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors#truncated_normal) you can get random values from a truncated random distribution, thus:

```
shape = [10,10] # variable shape
weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))
bias = tf.Variable(0.)
```

Comment: I ended up using `initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.01)`. Thanks for your help